Is there any resources that can be linked, in the architecture of machine language?
I want to see how each assembly or machine code functions like the add operation how it's physically made. If I ever want to recreate any assembly into minecraft Redstone for example I want to see how.
U tried looking at tutorials and websites but bound nothing.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has a bunch of links including x86 manuals, if that's an architecture you're interested in.  MIPS and RISC-V are simpler to decode.  For actual internals like an ALU, see things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor

Have a look at a MIPS datapath diagram.  This block diagram shows, at a high level, the arrangement of components that are necessary for the bulk of MIPS instruction set.  The control signals are shown in blue and they are (mostly) 1-bit operations, and the effectively turn on or off (i.e. set to listen-to/ignore) parts of the processor that are relevant/irrelevant for any given instruction.

The Arithmetic Logic Unit (ALU) is responsible for arithmetic operations. This video has a great chart of the gates involved. As for the logic instructions, they are just logic gates.
The stack instructions mostly move addresses or variables to and from the stack. In minecraft those could be recreated with music discs. This guy made an awesome project with them.

Thanks for the links. If you have more because the entirety of the assembly language consists of hundreds of diffrent operations. I want to know of have some resources that show how operations are wierd. If you have something like this link it like a university book or something.

@PeterCordes gave an amazing anwser, follow his links, there are a lot of good articles and manuals! Happy learning :D
